# JSON array Tabulator js table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tabulator

I have a `Tabulator` datatable in my `HTML` file. Looks like this:

```
<div class="example-table">/div>
```

I have a `JavaScript` file that would populate my table with data by calling a rest `API` that returns with a `JSON`.

This is how my `JS` file looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".example-table").tabulator({
        columns : [ {
            title : "ID",
            field : "myjson.firstname",
            width : 250
        }, {
            title : "Pred",
            field : "myjson.pred",
            sorter : "number",
            align : "left",
            formatter : "progress",
            width : 200
        }, ],
    });

    var tabledata = [];

    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:7001/MySerices/service/rest', function(json) {
        tabledata.append(json);
    });

    $(".example-table").tabulator("setData", tabledata);

});
```

And the `JSON` which the REST service returns with looks like this:

```
{"myjson":
[{"firstname":"Piter","pred":"0,616540492"},
{"firstname":"Piter","pred":"0,616540492"}
]}
```

The Tabulator table apears but without any data. If I check my JS log, I can see the request is done wihout any error, and i can see the JSON in my response.

Can you help me how can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: sorry, but i think my question is not about how asynchronous calls works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three major errors in your code.

**First**, your JSON response, the response should be as the tabulator js [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/3.3#set-data) shows:

```
//An array of objects not wrapped in an object
[
   {"firstname":"Piter","pred":"0,616540492"},
   {"firstname":"Parker","pred":"0,42325456"}
]
```

**Second**, the columns field should match each row:

```
$(".example-table").tabulator({
    columns : [ {
        title : "ID",
        field : "firstname",//changed here
        width : 250
    }, {
        title : "Pred",
        field : "pred",//and here
        sorter : "number",
        align : "left",
        formatter : "progress",
        width : 200
    }, ],
});
```

**Third**, `getJSON` is asynchronous, so you need to get and set the data only when the `response` arrives:

```
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:7001/MySerices/service/rest', function(response) {
    //response is already a parsed JSON
    $(".example-table").tabulator("setData", response);

});
```

> PS: arrays don't have the `append` method, you can use `unshift` or `push`to prepend or append data to the [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: Thank you so much! I have o modified my server side REST response too, but your soluion solved my probleme! Thank you!

Comment: @solarenqu no problem

Comment: only one more question, what do you think is it possible to load the table line by line? :)

Comment: @solarenqu like one by one with a delay?

Comment: Yes, with delay.. :)

Comment: @solarenqu yes it's possible, you can use jQuery for that btw, but I'm not a specialist in animation, there are infinite ways to do that, one of them is run through your response data using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [timeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) for delay.

Comment: @Lucas, you can pass the URL directly to the setData function and it will make the ajax request for you